# Why font get italic

Tags: fonts, corel-draw

I'm run a dual boot with Windows XP and Windows 7. I'm using CorelDraw. I do not have problem using XP fonts, but when I make a design and try to open in Windows 7's Arial Black font, it always displays in italics. The same design in XP has no italic effect. After removing the italic, the problem I'm getting after conversion or exporting to JPEG also makes it italic.

I have created a .gif of the problem I'm facing. I have the text and whenever I type in Arial Black Font, the default comes in italic, then I have to make it normal and non-italic. As you can see, when I move the text it's normal but the "shadow" looks italic. And finally, when I convert it also looks normal but after converting it's italic. This is a problem with the Arial Black font only. I have download the fresh font from website and copy pasted. Still same issue.

[image]

Comment: what version of coreldraw are you using?

Comment: older version CorelDraw 12

Comment: are you using FontNav, if not you can try uninstalling it, Otherwise, this was fixed in an update many years ago. Is your Corel up to date?

Comment: Where can I get FontNav? Setup link plz to download

Comment: Fontnav should be installed with your Corel Draw, you have to uninstall it. (remove it)

Comment: Is FontNav in-built with the setup to install

Comment: FONTNAV is installed when you install Corel Draw, but its a separate program. If you go to Control Panel and Programs, find Font Nav and uninstall it.

Comment: can you send me the link where can i download fontnav for coreldraw12 so that i can download and install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Corel\Corel Graphics 12
[image]

Click on FontNav Folder
[image]

Click on FontNav icon
[image]

A pop window of FontNav
[image]

After the pop window of FontNav seen on the right hand you will see no fonts install and on the left hand you will see the fonts list
Click on File > install Fonts
A pop window where the fonts install or just click ok
And all the fonts will install and you can see on the right hand window.

With my problem above i have fix the solution the result below. Now its no more italic after curve

[image]

**Note :** If you find in the right hand window same name font with different icon just delete the TT icon.